# Mongoose: How to use $gte and $lte into array with Aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have an mongoDB object like :

```
{
"Questions":[
  {
    "mark": 10
  },
  {
    "mark": 2
  },
  {
    "mark": 7
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to return such marks which greater than 2 and smaller than 8.

Output should look like :

```
{
"Questions":[ 
  {
    "mark": 2
  },
  {
    "mark": 7
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/jFhksSRIFA4

Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get filtered array using [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) and [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      Questions: {
        $filter: {
          "input": "$Questions",
          "as": "q",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              { $gte: [ "$$q.mark", 2] },
              { $lte: [ "$$q.mark", 8] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```